# Unable to use .env files with Vite and Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite, .env

I am using Vue 3 with vite as my dev server... I have two .env files configured for my vite setup, `.env` and `.env.development`, and I seem unable to use the variables within them...

`.env`

```
VITE_API_KEY="1234"
VITE_API_URL="https://www.myapi.com"
```

`.env.development`

```
VITE_API_KEY="5678"
VITE_API_URL="https://www.staging.myapi.com"
```

Could someone help me understand why when I use my variables like this `import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL`, I just get this in the console;
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VITE_API_URL')`, and if i use `process.` I get `Process is undefined`.

I'd also like to add I'm not using `dotenv` or anything like that...

Good trawl around StackOverflow, but nothing has helped me so far...

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Where are the `.env` files located? Are you setting the [`envPath`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#envdir)?

Comment: the `.env` files are in the root of my project, I have not set an envPath as most of the information I found omitted this...

Answer (score 0):

install this two package

```
env-cmd,
dotenv
```

package.json file add this cmd

```
script:{    
    "local": "env-cmd -f .env vite",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development vite", 
    //Other
}
```

using

const ApiBaseUrl =   import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL

local env run that time run `npm run local` development env run that time `npm run dev`

**add both .env file one more key `VITE_NODE_ENV=`**

Comment: I still get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VITE_API_URL')`. It's almost like `.env` files are blocked

Comment: try for .env.local not only for .env file

Answer (score 0):

So I've kind of solved it... Basically Vite doesn't load `.env` files by default as the files to load can only be determined after evaluating the Vite config, for example, the `root` and `envDir` options affect the loading behaviour. However, you can use the exported loadEnv helper to load the specific .env file if needed.

There is a way to load a specific `.env` file, but this still doesn't allow vite to access the `.env` variables in the `vite.config.js`